# IntegrityError when delete model instance

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models like

```
class A(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class B(models.Model):
   recommendation = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name="+")
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

When I remove the A model instance, I get something like:

```
IntegrityError: update or delete on table "myapp_a" violates foreign key constraint "myapp_relate_recommendation_id_4a7c5340_fk_myapp_a_id" on table "myapp_b"
Detail: Key (id)=(27527) is still referenced from table "myapp_b".
```

I can't figure out why it happens, I thought FKs should be deleted by default.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `on_delete` argument to your `recommendation` field:

**models.py**

```
class A(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class B(models.Model):
   recommendation = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name="+", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**Running `python manage.py shell`**

```
>>> from abtest.models import A, B
>>> a = A(title="test A title")
>>> a.save()
>>> a
<A: A object (1)>
>>> b = B(title="test B title", recommendation=a)
>>> b.save()
>>> b
<B: B object (1)>
>>> b.recommendation
<A: A object (1)>
>>> a.delete()
(2, {'abtest.B': 1, 'abtest.A': 1})
```

You can read more about how Django handles foreign key deletion [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

Comment: Well, I've already tried that and it didn't work. And I think models.CASCADE is default behavior.

Comment: What version of Django are you using? I just tested the solution I posted above using Django 2.0 and it works fine. In fact, `makemigrations` will only run if I add an `on_delete` argument to the ForeignKey field; otherwise, the migration throws an error. I've updated my response above with the output of my console.